# updation of date column of csv file using awk

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Rows present in csv file
eg.

```
POC,1234567890,2345678901,2014-06-03 09:20:43,250
```

I want to update only date column(4th column- date Time) not time of csv file. But my awk command is updating complete 4th column and time is getting truncated which i dont want, How can i do this?

Awk Command

```
awk -F, 'NR>2 && NR<=1000{$4="2015-07-01";}1' OFS=, Input.csv> Output.csv
```

Time should not be truncated in output.csv file.(Date and time are separated by space)

output should be

```
POC,1234567890,2345678901,2015-07-01 09:20:43,250
```

Note-
1. All the dates in the original files are not the same but they all need to be transformed to the same new date.
2.Date format in original file can be of any format(dd-M-yyyy/dd-MM-yyyy/dd-MMM-yy)

Answer (score 2):

```
sub(/2014-06-03/, "2015-07-01", $4)
```

You've not really indicated whether all the dates in the original are the same and whether they all need to be transformed to the same new date, but the `sub` command does a regex-based substitution.

> All the dates in the original files are not the same but they all need to be transformed to the same new date.

So the regex needs to be a bit more complex:

```
sub(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/, "2015-07-01", $4)
```

You can probably change the first `[0-9]` to `[12]` if not leave it as 2.  You can play other games (`[01][0-9]` for the month, etc).  But sometimes simple is good enough.  You're not validating the old date; you're replacing it.

Comment: ... All the dates in the original files are not the same but they all need to be transformed to the same new date.

Comment: Date format in original file can be of any format(dd-M-yyyy/dd-MM-yyyy/dd-MMM-yy), but it will be same in complete file? and also code simplicity at the cost of a few CPU cycles.

Comment: Go learn your regexes for the strings of digits; it can all be done in one, though it might be clearer in several.  The `dd-MMM-yy` notation is messier; presumably, the MMM is names like JAN to DEC (or local equivalents).  You would be well advised to use an alternative sub for that.  You can make the replacement string into a variable: `new_date = "2015-07-01"` and then use that in the various `sub` function calls.

Comment: Or you could go with `sub(/^[^ ]*/, new_date, $4)` which simply looks for any sequence of non-blank characters and replaces it with the new date.  Having looked, I see that's what [nikhil](http://stackoverflow.com/users/435545/nikhil) suggests in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31422937/15168), though he spells 'not a space' using `[^[:space]]`.  You can insist on one or more characters there if you prefer by replacing `*` with `+`, or you can use `{6,10}` to require 6-10 characters (allowing for 1-1-15 to 2015-01-01), etc.  The options are legion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script to replace only date component from 4th column.

```
awk -F, 'NR>2 && NR<=1000{sub(/[^[:space:]]*/,"2015-07-01",$4);}1' OFS=, Input.csv> Output.csv
```

Comment: Will u please explain this part------[^[:space:]]*

Comment: [^[:space:]]* is everything but no space.  For current example, it will be the date component.

Answer (score 0):

As `$4` has a fixed value, here's a quick and *ugly* way:

```
awk 'NR>2 && NR<=1000{$4="2015-07-01";}1' FS="( |,)" OFS="," Input.csv |sed -e "s/-01,/-01 /" > Output.csv
```

Personally I prefer Jonathan's flow.

Comment: You should probably explain that editing field 4 means that the output line is reformatted with the commas separating the fields, but the `sed` post-processes the result to replace that comma with a blank as in the original.  As you say, it is a little ugly.